# calling mysql procedure return empty result

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7, mysql-workbench

when i call procedure it gives me empty result

```
   call hussian('prstate','table_1','column1,column2,column3',1)
```

it run but gives empty result, please help me...

```
 DELIMITER // 

 CREATE PROCEDURE hussain(IN src_col varchar(20), 
                     IN tblname varchar(100), 
                     IN col_names varchar(100), 
                     IN _leadid int)

 BEGIN
    IF (col_names  = 'column1' AND col_names  = 'column2'  AND col_names = 'column3')
THEN

    SET @sql = CONCAT('insert into ', tblname, '(',col_names,')', ' select ' ,src_col,',','firstname,lastname from tbllead where id = ',_leadid); 
    PREPARE s1 from @sql;
     EXECUTE s1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
 END IF;
  END //
  DELIMITER ;
```

it insert data into table when i romove if condition.....

Comment: `SELECT @sql` to see what you have constructed.

Answer (score 1):

Basically

**'column1' 'column2' 'column3'** is different than **'column1,column2,column3'**

So, you must compare the whole string:

```
 BEGIN
IF (col_names  = 'column1,column2,column3')
THEN
.
.
.
```

If you want to compare each variable separately, then you must pass them separate in your procedure call:

Call:

```
call hussian('prstate','table_1','column1','column2','column3',1)
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE hussain(IN src_col varchar(20), 
                         IN tblname varchar(100), 
                         IN col_names1 varchar(100), 
                         IN col_names2 varchar(100), 
                         IN col_names3 varchar(100), 
                         IN _leadid int)
```

Comment: @tajamulhussain Mark the answer as a solution in such case.

Comment: @tajamulhussain please mark the answer as the solution for your question.